# Bounty is dangerously close to the checkmark

Tags: bug, design, bounties, accepted-answer

> [image]

The checkmark moved a bit down (relative to the votes) with the last redesign, but bounty didn't. So now it is they are too close too each other.

Please move the bounty down a bit, but don't touch the checkmark; cuz as it stays now, on mobile it is easier to click it and not touch the downvote accidentally, while it became more difficult to click the bounty without clicking the checkmark and vice-versa; and also it is *just not beautiful*.

Comment: -1; the freehand red line is covering the glorious whitespace. (jk. I +1'd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look like it is endangered anymore, does it? Or, divorce - who knows. Anyway - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

> [image]